# How can I add bid option in table?

Tags: php, html-table

I am beginner in php... 
How to create a bids option from the table:

```
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Current Location</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Preferred Treatment Location</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Treatment & Surgery</th>
        <th>Enter date</th>
        <th>Medical Condition of Patient</th>
        <th>BIDS</th>
    </tr>
        <?php
            //Create Connection with MySQL Database
            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root123');

            //Select Database
            if(!mysqli_select_db($con,'medical'))
            {
                echo "Database Not Selected";
            }
            //Select Query
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_detail";

            //Execute the SQL query
            $records = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['fname']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['lname']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['clocation']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['country']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['state']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['city']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['treatment']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['country1']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['state1']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['city1']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['surgery']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['medicond']."</td>";
            }
        ?>
</table>
```

Can you please help...

Comment: make you purpose clear, what issue you encounter?

Comment: Don't understand neither.. :(